# Price of the product includes taxes, but actual price is reduced by the Tax Rule

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax

**TL;DR**: my Magento 1.9 shop handles product prices including taxes. But a new Tax Rule reduces the price to be paid by the customer. Why??? Complete issue description follows.

I'm the developer with a multi-website Magento 1.9.2.1 instance. Prices for the whole catalog are managed "including taxes" => if we insert a 100 € price, the customer is expected to pay 100 € for the product.

Every product has the same Tax Class. It's called `IVA 22%`, but that's just a label. It actually means "it's a product with the standard tax rate".

Up until today, we had a standard "Tax Rates" table: one entry for every country we ship to, with the same `Rate Percent` set to 22% for every country. This is the one for France:

[image: Tax Rate France 22%]

This is the related rule:

[image: Tax Rule]

This worked great! On the frontend, said product with a 100 € price tag could be purchased for 100 €. Under the hood, the sale was handled as 81.96 € + 22%.

Now we must change the tax rate depending on the shipping country. So the same Tax Rate for France was updated like this (note the `Rate percent` now set to 20 instead of 22):

[image: Tax Rate France 20%]

We must keep the prices unchanged. The product with a 100 € price tag must continue to be sold for 100 €. Under the hood, we expect to be managed correctly based on the shipping country. For France, this would be 83.33 € + 20%.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. When the customer tries to buy said 100 € product and selects one of the country with a different tax, the price... gets lower. I understood that:

1. the 100 € price still gets handled as "81.96 € + 22%" (22% being the original tax rate)
2. the system takes the 81.96 € price and adds the country-specific tax
3. results: the customer pays "81.96 € + 20%" = 98,35 € instead of 100 €

I've already tried to remove the original 22% tax rule, re-index everything and also to ask God for mercy. Nothing works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found! [set Enable Cross Border Trade](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/tax-cross-border-price.html)